# is it possible to disable python setup.py install?

Tags: python, setup.py

Is it possible to disable python setup.py install, for example:

1. showing a warning message saying that install is not supported
   or
2. run python setup.py develop automatically instead of insall

I am new to use this tool, and I tried to check the documentation about setup.py, but didn't figure out if it is possible to support one option only. Can anyone give me some ideas here? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Is this a package you wrote or a third party?

Comment: it is a package wrote by myself

Comment: The whole point of `setup.py` is to be an installer. Could we get some more context here? What option do you want specifically that isn't install but needs to go into the `setup.py` file?

Answer (score 0):

pip uses `setup.py` internally so directly disabling `setup.py` is not a good idea. maybe add this to the **top** of your `setup.py` package:

```py
if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("manual use of setup.py is not supported")
    exit()
```

This way if the script was called manually it will warn the user and exit.